# Umbraco - Encode URL following the same rules as defined in the request handler settings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

In Umbraco, i want to generate URL encoded string as it was a genuine Umbraco path.

So if i have the following relative path:

> /products/4/drinking glass

I want it encoded like this:

> /products/4/drinking-glass/

As it would if i used NiceUrl on a published content object.
Following the same rules as described in the request handler part of umbracoSettings.config.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer after searching a bit more.

Umbraco made an extension method for this purpose:

```
"drinking glass".ToUrlSegment()
```

Which provides a safe way to generate custom url encoded strings.